# How can I have my own custom invoice number pattern?

Tags: commerce

Hi Im trying to make different pattern for the invoice in Drupal 9.
I have products with two kind of price one is for particular and the other one is for profesional.

i would like to have two pattern number for the invoice, for particular 22-ES-00001 and for profesional 22-ES-P-00001.
I already create the two kind of pattern number and i have two kind of invoice type and also asign each pattern number to the invoice type.

I just need to associate the invoice type to the role. But dont know the way of how to do it any one have any idea about how can i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The invoice number is generated from `Invoice::presave();`, using the following code:

```
if ($this->getState()->getId() != 'draft' && empty($this->getInvoiceNumber())) {
  /** @var \Drupal\commerce_number_pattern\Entity\NumberPatternInterface $number_pattern */
  $number_pattern = $invoice_type->getNumberPattern();
  if ($number_pattern) {
    $invoice_number = $number_pattern->getPlugin()->generate($this);
    $this->setInvoiceNumber($invoice_number);
  }
}
```

What I'd do if I were you, in order for this code to be bypassed is that I'd set a "fake" temporary invoice number on invoice creation (by reacting to the `InvoiceEvents::INVOICE_CREATE` event.

Then from the same event subscriber reacting to `InvoiceEvents::INVOICE_PRESAVE` I'd add my own logic to invoice the right number pattern plugin.

Setting an invoice number on invoice creation would help bypassing the comemrce_invoice code, and you could have your own logic running on invoice presave.

Here's the documentation around event subscribers in case you need help with that.

Comment: They usually need to whole event subscriber sampled.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will try to make it.